# IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error:

Tags: python-2.7, exception

I am downloading a lot of files from the web. The code creates a path for the file to be downloaded depending on the name of the file. The fact is I have IOError: [Errno 5] Input/Output error along the way. This error does come randomly when downloading the files. The first time it came up after downloading 100 files, the next time after downloading about 1400 files. I am not sure why. This is the code I wrote. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

> File "download.py", line 13, in downloadFile
>
> > output.write(wmvfile.read())
> >
> > > output = open(str(path) + name + '.wmv', 'wb)

```
    def downloadFile(url, name, path):
      try: 
        wmvfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        global count
        count += 1
        print count
        print "path: ", path, "name: ", name
        output = open(str(path) + name + '.wmv', 'wb')
        output.write(wmvfile.read())
        output.close()

      except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        print 'url error :', url
        path = '/Volumes/Ross/PoliticsVideos/logfile/httperror/'

        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(path)):
           os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path))

        with open(path + 'log.txt', 'a') as output:
           output.write(url + '\n')
           output.close()

      except IOError as io:
        print 'IO error:', url
        path = '/Volumes/Ross/PoliticsVideos/logfile/ioerror/'
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(path)):
           os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path))

        with open(path + 'log.txt', 'a') as output:
           output.write(url + '\n')
           output.close()
```